# How do I save an multidim array to Properties.settings in C#

Tags: c#

How do I save multidimensional array to Properties.Settings? If I can't do this or can't it easily, how can I save a single dimensional array to Properties.Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties.Settings has a **System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection** that you can use.  It does not have anything for multidimensional arrays.  To save you will need to iterate through your array and use StringCollection.Add method to add each element of your array to the collection.

[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What about saving integer arrays or does that include it?

Comment: only strings.  unfortunately you will have to convert.

Comment: feel free to accept that as the answer if it worked for you.Thanks